# Windbg preview kd dump command don't perform correctly

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am using Windbg Preview to debug a common program. I am using [`kd` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/k--kb--kc--kd--kp--kp--kv--display-stack-backtrace-) to dump the stack,
but I found it doesn't print the corresponding memory just from esp down,
as the `r` command show that esp points to 0x29af810 , `kd` just shows me the memory from 0x29af814 and higher, I thought step in one instruction will make it correct itself, but it appear to stay the same. Is it a known bug of Windbg Preview?

[image: Here is the picture of that]

It seems produce a wrong answer even at the first break.

```
(3f44.87c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first 
chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=189c0000 edx=00000000 esi=77d52054 
edi=77d5261c
eip=77df1ba2 esp=005bf984 ebp=005bf9b0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr 
na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             
efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b:
77df1ba2 cc              int     3
0:000> kd 10
005bf9b0  005bfc10
005bf9b4  77dec0a8 ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x1c98
005bf9b8  c12453e3
005bf9bc  0286d000
005bf9c0  00000000
005bf9c4  02870000
005bf9c8  00640062
005bf9cc  02af2738
005bf9d0  005bfb44
005bf9d4  00000000
005bf9d8  00000201
005bf9dc  00000000
005bf9e0  005bfb40
005bf9e4  00000000
005bf9e8  02af4198
005bf9ec  77e65d00 ntdll!LdrpWorkQueue
```

Comment: sorry I am new here , unfamiliar with how to post something , I just launch a older version  of windbg in my sdk and it does support `kd` , but its behavior is still incorrect, and I referenced the manual , it told me : "The kd command is equivalent to a dds (Display Memory) command that uses the stack address as its parameter." as I follow some instructions, It seems that `kd` indeed dump the stack from ebp instead of esp, and follow the change of esp to change the view , but I am not very sure about it.

Comment: yeah, that perform correctly, but it means I need to type `dps esp L4` , a considerable cost than `kd 4` (if could print correctly), also I want to know why it lead to such a weird outcome.  And about the start address ,in fact I try some different exe built by vs2019 in Windbg Preview, and observe that all of their print start from ebp  when use `kd` at the first breakpoint (`LdrpDoDebuggerBreak`), It seems that `kd` produce a wrong answer even when debugger first break into the debugee.

Comment: but a farer debugging confuse me, as I assemble two statements to observe `kd` output's change, and find it change without any signal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kd prints the raw dwords from the **Frame Offset or ChildEBP**  (see edit )
you can check frame offset with .frame command
@esp can be different

are you observing something different ?

```
0:000> .frame
00 00a3fc94 00f367ba cdb!wmain+0xb
0:000> k 1
ChildEBP RetAddr
00a3fc94 00f367ba cdb!wmain+0xb
0:000> kd 4
00a3fc94  00a3fcd4
00a3fc98  00f367ba cdb!__wmainCRTStartup+0x107
00a3fc9c  00000001
00a3fca0  050f2210
0:000> ?@esp
Evaluate expression: 10746476 = 00a3fa6c
0:000>
```

a full call stack for a random process its frames or ChildEBP and the esp Register in RegisterContext if printed below

```
0:000> .frame 0
00 00a3fc94 00f367ba cdb!wmain+0xb
0:000> .frame 1
01 00a3fcd4 75346359 cdb!__wmainCRTStartup+0x107
0:000> .frame 2
02 00a3fce4 776687a4 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x19
0:000> .frame 3
03 00a3fd40 77668774 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
0:000> .frame 4
04 00a3fd50 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:000> .frame 5
Cannot find frame 0x5, previous scope unchanged
04 00a3fd50 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:000> .frame /c 0 ; kd 2
00 00a3fc94 00f367ba cdb!wmain+0xb
eax=00a40000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00f3f2f8 edx=00000080 esi=00000001 edi=00000000
eip=00f33c99 esp=00a3fa6c ebp=00a3fc94 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
cdb!wmain+0xb:
00f33c99 a1448ff300      mov     eax,dword ptr [cdb!__security_cookie (00f38f44)] ds:002b:00f38f44=4d19f94c
00a3fc94  00a3fcd4
00a3fc98  00f367ba cdb!__wmainCRTStartup+0x107
0:000> .frame /c 1 ; kd 2
01 00a3fcd4 75346359 cdb!__wmainCRTStartup+0x107
eax=00a40000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00f3f2f8 edx=00000080 esi=00000001 edi=00000000
eip=00f367ba esp=00a3fc9c ebp=00a3fcd4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
cdb!__wmainCRTStartup+0x107:
00f367ba 83c40c          add     esp,0Ch
00a3fcd4  00a3fce4
00a3fcd8  75346359 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x19
0:000> .frame /c 2 ; kd 2
02 00a3fce4 776687a4 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x19
eax=00a40000 ebx=0095f000 ecx=00f3f2f8 edx=00000080 esi=00f368c0 edi=00f368c0
eip=75346359 esp=00a3fcdc ebp=00a3fce4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x19:
75346359 50              push    eax
00a3fce4  00a3fd40
00a3fce8  776687a4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
0:000> .frame /c 3 ; kd 2
03 00a3fd40 77668774 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
eax=00a40000 ebx=0095f000 ecx=00f3f2f8 edx=00000080 esi=75346340 edi=00f368c0
eip=776687a4 esp=00a3fcec ebp=00a3fd40 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f:
776687a4 e9fea00300      jmp     ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x3a132 (776a28a7)
00a3fd40  00a3fd50
00a3fd44  77668774 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:000> .frame /c 4 ; kd 2
04 00a3fd50 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
eax=00a40000 ebx=0095f000 ecx=00f3f2f8 edx=00000080 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=77668774 esp=00a3fd48 ebp=00a3fd50 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b:
77668774 cc              int     3
00a3fd50  00000000
00a3fd54  00000000
0:000> .frame /c 5 ; kd 2
Cannot find frame 0x1, previous scope unchanged
04 00a3fd50 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
eax=00a40000 ebx=0095f000 ecx=00f3f2f8 edx=00000080 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=77668774 esp=00a3fd48 ebp=00a3fd50 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b:
77668774 cc              int     3
00a3fd50  00000000
00a3fd54  00000000
0:000>
```